# Divide and conquer to find the max sum sublist of a list

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Given a list L, which two items that are adjacent in the list cannot both be picked in the sublist S, and  list L does not contain repeated values. I want to design an algorithm using divide-and-conquer approach that outputs a sublist S that maximises the sum of its elements. For instance, if`L = [1, 0, 5, 3, 2, 7, 9, 15, 6, 4, 13]`, then `S = [1, 5, 7, 15, 13]`.
The following codes I wrote are not working and I think it's not a divide-and-conquer approach.

```
def bestsublist(l):
    sublist = []
    n = len(l)
    totalsum = [None] * (n + 1)
    totalsum[n] = 0
    for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
        totalsum[i] = max(l[i] + totalsum[min(i+2,n)],totalsum[min(i+1,n)])
        if l[i] + totalsum[min(i+2,n)] > totalsum[min(i+1,n)]:
            sublist.append(l[l[i] + totalsum[min(i+2,n)] - 1])
        else:
            sublist.append(l[totalsum[min(i+1,n)] - 1])

    return sublist
```

Comment: Why does it need to be divide-and-conquer? Dynamic programming seems to be more applicable and it seems to be what you have tried in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost correct. The only thing wrong with it is how you build the solution sublist.

The problem is that you append to it before you finish traversing the  entire list, so you don't know yet if you're going to use the element or not.

So to fix it just run through the list again and build the sublist. Here's how it would look:

```
....
for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
    totalsum[i] = max(l[i] + totalsum[min(i+2,n)],totalsum[min(i+1,n)])

i = 0
while i < n:
   if l[i] + totalsum[min(i+2,n)] > totalsum[min(i+1,n)]:
        sublist.append(l[i])
        i += 2
    else:
        i += 1
return sublist
```

P.s. Your solution is dynamic programming, not divide-and-conquer.